# Changing Entire Column to Date Type in SQL

Tags: sql, ddl, exasol

I am trying to convert the datatype of a column `Confirmation_Date`to date type but unable to to do so, the Column is of varchar type and SER_MUHAMMAD_MALLICK.user is the tablel. Iam using the following code snippet.

```
SELECT CONVERT (datetime, Confirmation_Date , 104) FROM USER_MUHAMMAD_MALLICK.user_upsells;
```

I am receiving the following error message when I run this code

```
SQL Error [42000]: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER_LIST_ [line 1, column 17] (Session: 1729360210797461536)
```

Comment: for changing the datatype you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15   (example  Changing the data type of a column)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am using Exasol

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this I am using Dbeaver  for sql statements and Exasol as my databse

Answer (score 0):

You can use [alter table modify column](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql/alter_table(column).htm). For example to convert a `VARCHAR` column to `DATE`:

```sql
create schema s;
create table t(c varchar(2000000));
insert into t values '2020-01-01', '2021-05-30';

/*
COLUMN_NAME SQL_TYPE              NULLABLE DISTRIBUTION_KEY PARTITION_KEY 
----------- --------------------- -------- ---------------- ------------- 
C           VARCHAR(2000000) UTF8 TRUE     FALSE            FALSE         
*/
describe t;
alter table t modify column c date ;
/*
COLUMN_NAME SQL_TYPE NULLABLE DISTRIBUTION_KEY PARTITION_KEY 
----------- -------- -------- ---------------- ------------- 
C           DATE     TRUE     FALSE            FALSE         
*/
describe t;
```

Note that the varchar values must be of the correct date format. If you have a different date format you need to specify the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter with [ALTER SESSION](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql/alter_session.htm#NLS_DATE_FORMAT):

```sql
create or replace table t(c varchar(2000000));
insert into t values '01.01.2020', '30.05.2020';
-- data exception - invalid character value for cast; Value: '01.01.2020' Format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
alter table t modify column c date ;

alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd.mm.yyyy';

-- works now
alter table t modify column c date ;
```